# ChatterMessage Trigger not working for Community User

Tags: trigger, community, chatter

I want to monitor the ChatterMessage Activity of a community User, so i enable the Manage Chatter Messages system permission on a cloned System Administrator profile and write the trigger. This ChatterMessage trigger is working fine if we logged in by System Admin in the internal Salesforce org and send a private message but this trigger is not running when a message sends by the Community User. Is there any permission missing/issue or any other workaround to monitor the ChatterMessage Activity of a community User?

Comment: For my requirement, I created a trigger on FeedItem sObject and its working fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChatterMessage trigger was not running for the community user, so we used a trigger on FeedItem and it was working fine in the context of community user.

```
trigger FeedItemTrigger on FeedItem (before insert) {
    for(FeedItem feedItemObj : Trigger.New){
        //Do Something Here.
    }
}
```